# Trying to add Session to MVC 6

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add Sessions to a MV6 application, I added the dependency, but when I try to add it to the using statement in Visual Studio 2015 it fails, it doesn't recognice the session assembly.

You can see a screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Zf0.jpg

Is this a bug or am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with the KRE version that you are using, your session package is beta3 and you are using beta1, pchange your session package to be beta1

Comment: I swiched to beta1, still having the same problem.

Comment: Do you know what kre are you using ? and what version of the VS are you using

Comment: Can you delete the the packages from your user folder c:\users\your username\.kpm

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Deleting the packages in user folder c:\users\your username.kpm fixed the problem, thank you Son_of_Sam.